# Mahalanobis distance with LDL decomposition

Tags: covariance-matrix, kalman-filter, matrix-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition

I've got an extended Kalman filter with innovation covariance defined as $\mathbf{W}=\mathbf{H}\mathbf{P}\mathbf{H}^\textrm{T} + \mathbf{R}$. I want to know the squared Mahalanobis distance $\|z\|^2$ between a (vector) measurement residual $\mathbf{y}$ and the matrix $\mathbf{W}$, e.g., $\|z\|^2 = \mathbf{y}^\textrm{T} \mathbf{W}^{-1} \mathbf{y}$.

At first I was using the Cholesky decomposition and then forward substitution to solve for $\mathbf{L}\mathbf{z}=\mathbf{y}$. Then, $\|z\|^2 = \mathbf{z}^\textrm{T}\mathbf{z}$.

However, sometimes $\mathbf{W}$ does not appear to be positive definite, though it is symmetric. This seems to happen when — based on the residuals — the Mahalanobis distance should be quite large. I can't do a Cholesky decomposition in these cases, so instead I do an LDL' decomposition, and say that $\|z\|^2 = \mathbf{z}^\textrm{T} \mathbf{D}^{-1} \mathbf{z} = \sum_i^{n-1} \frac{z_i^2}{d_i}$.

That gives me a reasonable value in some cases, but sometimes diagonal elements are negative. That gives me a very large negative squared Mahalanobis distance, which doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

I figure I'm making some math error, but I'm also unsure that it should ever be necessary to do an LDL' decomposition. Might something be wrong with my computation of $\mathbf{W}$?

What does it mean when my sample covariance is not positive definite? How should I decompose this in order to compute the squared Mahalanobis distance?

Answer (score 2):

When $W$ is positive semidefinite but singular there will be entries in $D$ that are effectively 0 but due to round-off error might have very small negative values.  A common approach would be to set a tolerance and consider all negative values of $D$ and small positive entries in $D$ less than the tolerance to be effectively 0.

Comment: Can you give me a little bit more justification? I'm actually seeing some really large negative values in D (for example, for one measurement 3-vector, I get -1.8111752954e+206, 4.8592888658e+190, -7.4324207769e+191). I already have near-zero tolerance checks on all divisions.

Comment: There is obviously something else wrong then- if your matrix is positive semidefinite then all of the entries in $D$ should be greater than or equal to 0- that's a fact of linear algebra.  Can you check the eigenvalues of your $W$ matrix to see that they are alll greater than or equal to 0?  What about $P$ and $R$?

Comment: Okay, it looks like it's a snowball effect. $\mathbf{W}$ has a slightly negative diagonal, which causes later $\mathbf{W}$'s to have extremely negative diagonals. But $\mathbf{R}$, the "measurement noise covariance," is just a diagonal, basically $\varepsilon \mathbf{I}$, so does this imply that my scalar multiplier $\varepsilon$ is not large enough?

Comment: What about P?  It should be positive definite as well.

Comment: Yes, and if W stops being positive definite, P usually stops being positive definite. But why positive definite and not positive semi-definite, out of curiosity?

Comment: From the numerical computing point of view it's effectively impossible to decide whether a matrix is actually positive semidefinite or whether it's indefinite, because you can't compute eigenvalues exactly.  From a modeling perspective you generally want to avoid the degenerate distributions associated with positive semidefinite but singular covariance matrices.

Comment: In other words, cases where the Cholesky decomposition don't work are probably not going to provide much helpful information to the filter?